# Error: Stream is closed while reading file

Tags: java, io, itext

I am trying to modify existing PDF file and displaying on new browser. But i am getting "java.io.IOException: Stream Closed" exception and the file is not opening .Only browser is opened.
Code:

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=ChallanStamped.pdf");
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("G:/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/Programs/Job Application Site/WebContent/Documents/Challan1.pdf");
        try {
               ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                   
               pdfReader = new PdfReader(in, null);
               pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos);
               for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){ 

                  PdfContentByte pdfcontent = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);                
                  pdfcontent.beginText();
                  ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL, "1234", 500, 428, 0); /*Do not change this values*/
                  ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, "ABC", 500, 407, 0);      
                  ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, "05/10/1983", 500, 386, 0);                    
                  pdfcontent.endText();            
            }   
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read()) != -1) {                       
                   os.write(len);
                }   
                os.flush();
                os.close();
           try {
                pdfStamper.close();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           pdfReader.close();
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Solution: After writting content to pdfclose pdfstamper and then `OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();`. And write this outputstream to baos. and then flush os.

Comment: You shouldn't be closing the response's `OutputStream`, that's handled for you by the servlet container. It also causes interesting (read: bad) things to happen if you do close it.

Comment: @Kartic i tried that way too but still its same.Can you tell me what should be the sequence to close. like i am closing outputstream then pdfstamper and then pdfreader. Is the sequence causing error?

Comment: @JonK thanks but even if i do not close outputStream the problem persist.

Comment: It's possible that invoking `close()` on the `pdfStamper` object also closes the `pdfReader` object that you instantiated it with. It's not clear from the itext documentation if this is the case or not, but if the source code is accessible you should be able to tell.

Comment: @JonK yes it is from pdfstamper , because  if i comment code to write into pdf file it runs fine and file can be displayed in new window. but i want to write in file so it is allowing me to do that.

Comment: Can you segregate your operations like : 1. do pdf stamping and close it 2. do write pdf into output stream

Comment: You copy the contents of an `InputStream` to the response output (`while ((len = in.read()) != -1) { os.write(len); } `) after it already has been completely consumed (`pdfReader = new PdfReader(in, null);`). Thus, you copy nothing.

Comment: @mkl then what should be the flow? Can you please tell me.

Comment: You want to display the modified PDF. Thus, you will want to copy the output of the `PdfStamper` to the response output, i.e. the contents of `baos`.In contrast to your code, though, you have to wait until after `pdfStamper.close()` to do so, otherwise the end of the file is missing.

Comment: still no luck. tried @mkl approach too.

Comment: Finally its done.Now thinks it was a Silly mistake after spending a day on this issue.

Comment: Great! Please create an answer to your question and include the final, working code. After some hours you will (I think) be allowed to accept your own answer.